# Get "category level" for products in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, category

How to get Category level of product using product id ?

Comment: can you please explain what exactly you need

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Any product can be placed in several categories. What do you mean by "Category level of Product"?

Comment: level: ("Indicates the depth of the category within the tree")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that single product will assign in multiple categories. So, you can get category level using this below way :

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
 */
protected $productFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository
 */
protected $categoryRepository;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory      $productFactory
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository  $categoryRepository
 */
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
    ....
) {
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
}
```

From above code, You need to inject these both class in your construct. After that you can use this below code in your function.

```
$product = $this->productFactory->create()->load(1); //Add product id
    $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
    foreach ($cats as $key => $value) {
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($value);
        echo "Category ID : " . $category->getId() . " Category Level : " . $category->getLevel() . "<br/>";
    }
```

**Remove generated and clean cache.**

Hope, It's helpful for you.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, let me check.

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal... Update?

Comment: I haven't test it yet, but it seems to be valid answer, let me upvote for  now.

Comment: Okay. Please check it and mark as accepted so, it will helpful for others. Happy to Help :)